# Need to replace space with &nbsp;

Tags: special-characters

I'm trying to replace all spaces in a text with the HTML space.

```
cat test.txt | sed -e 's/ /&nbsp;/g'
```

But it returs without the & sign.

```
This nbsp;is nbsp;a nbsp;sample nbsp;text.
```

How do I make this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/ /\&nbsp;/g'
```

Note the `\` before the `&`. Escape your characters.